# LibBSON export to buffer

Tags: c, bson, mongodb-c

I'm searching for a way to copy a [BSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSON) document to a buffer or into a file using the C-library [libbson](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-c-driver/tree/master/src/libbson).

I think I'm missing something - any help is appreciated.

Comment: What format do you have the document in?

Comment: I added two links to the relevant source pages.

Comment: @immibis the document is on heap accessed via a bson_t pointer. Is that what you meant with format?

Comment: bson_as_canonical_extended_json() may do the trick. Is there a good way to export bson in binary format as e.g. mongodump does?

Comment: @zille yep. I was thinking you might've had it as a char array and be barking up the wrong tree :P

Comment: @immibis okay. I tried half a day playing around with bson_writer_t. Wasn't successful though. canonical extended json is 1kb larger but has no information loss unlike json itself. So I'm sticking to that now.

Answer (score 1):

[bson_as_canonical_extended_json](http://mongoc.org/libbson/current/bson_as_canonical_extended_json.html) exports BSON into UTF-8 without loss of information.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need buffer data, you can use bson_get_data :

```
bson_t * bson = bson_new();
///// Fill with data

// Get data buffer
const char * data = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(bson_get_data(bson));
int length = bson->len;
```